# jQuery animate horizontal slide across page

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, slide

Hey all, another interesting one,

I'm building a menu that will slide across the entire width of the page (width:100%;) and need some help. I have an arrow button floating on the right side of the page that will trigger a menu bar to slide out when clicked. I'd like the arrow button to slide out in front of it and once all the way across change the arrow image to it's opposite file.

The big issue is that the width and height of these need to be flexible to allow for varying content. I've got a feeble attempt at making it work, but I know that I'm missing a whole lot of factors here. My code doesn't even touch moving the arrow button along with the rest.. and that's not for lack of effort!

Any help? Thank you!

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
     <div class="trans" id="trigger">
          <img class="arrow_small" src="images/left_small.png" alt="slide out menu" />
     </div>
     <div id="slider">
          <div class="trans" id="overlay"></div>
          <div id="content">
               <p>this is the content</p>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main {
    width:100%;
    height:306px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-153px;
    position:absolute;
}
#trigger {
    width:30px;
    height:100%;
    float:right;
    background-color:#000;
    position:relative;
    z-index:3;
}
.arrow_small {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-6px;
    margin-top:-12px;
}
#overlay {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
#content {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//hide functions
    $('#slider').css('display', 'none');
//menu slide out
    $('#trigger').click(function (){
        var bar = $('#slider');
            bar.show(function(){
                this.animate({'marginRight':'100%'},1000);
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: Here is an other approach of [horizontal page sliding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414642/responsive-horizontal-page-sliding-navigation/24465646#24465646)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? Try this out in your browser:

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
 <div id="slider">
 &nbsp;
      <div id="image">
        <p>Image would go here</p>
      </div>
      <div id="content">
        <p>content...</p>
      </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#slider {
    width: 6%;
    height: 350px;
    top: 33%;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
.arrow_small {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-6px;
    margin-top:-12px;
}
#image {
    width: 75px;
    background-color: black;
    position:relative;
    color: white;
    float: left;
}
#content {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 100px;
    color: white;
}
```

js:

```
    $(function() {
    $('#image').toggle(function (){
        $("#slider").animate({"width":"100%"}, 1000);
    }, function() {
        $("#slider").animate({"width":"6%"}, 1000);
    });
});
```

I removed the image you had in your only because I didn't have it and wanted to test it locally with text. Hope this helps!

Comment: the javascript is certainly more elegant.. thank you! one issue: when you click on content within the slider it closes. anyway to make the content free of the trigger? something like slider with the exception of #content that way as the content dynamically changes what's left of the uncovered slider will work as the trigger.

Thank you so much!

Comment: You're very welcome. Glad it helped. I've the javascript in my original post. Instead of toggling on the entire slider div, it will now toggle only when the image div is clicked (you could even have it toggle only when the image is clicked if you wanted). Once the menu has slid out, you have to click on the image div in order to close it, and clicking on the content area will not slide it back in.

Comment: Works beautifully. I'd love to get your opinion on the best way to change the "#image" source once the sliders width animation has completed, and then change it back to the original source once it has finished closing. Thoughts? Here's the question I have posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060693/jquery-dynamically-alternate-between-image-sources-within-an-animated-div

Comment: Great! :) I'll try to check that question out sometime tonight.

Comment: Just took a look, and "mu is too short"'s answer seemed to cover it pretty well. You'll DEFINITELY want to use the callbacks. Unfortunately, I don't have editing privileges and can't freely comment yet, so I thought I'd post this here.