# how to implement that moving box like thing (screen paper?) of the webpage?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

if you put your mouse on the leftmost part of the home page [www.techants.com](http://www.techants.com), a box moves on to the front side. I tried to look at the code and thought it might be called *screen paper* as this name is used inside the code. Can any one tell which script is used there? How can I implement such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/slideinmenu.htm.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using jQuery, perhaps this thread could get you started:
[jQuery animate horizontal slide across page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048260/jquery-animate-horizontal-slide-across-page)

If you want it sliding in from the left, you could replace

```
#slider {
    right: 0;
}
```

by

```
#slider {
    left: 0;
}
```

...which would make it position itself at 0 pixels from the left, rather than the right.

If you want to reduce its width, alter the javascript line

```
$("#slider").animate({"width":"100%"}, 1000);
```

to whatever width you require (the percentage part)... the '1000' dictates the speed (in this case 1000 milliseconds).